# Why does linear independence of solutions to a second order ODE imply generality?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

First of all, I've searched this site for an answer and found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626362/why-does-the-sum-of-two-linearly-independent-solutions-of-a-second-order-homogen) question, but the answers did not tell what I want to know.
If we have a second order homogeneous differential equation

$$ p(t) y'' + q(t) y' + r(t) y = 0 $$

and two solutions $y_1, y_2$, I know that:

- Their linear combinations will be solutions as well
- For such a solution to be general, the two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ must be linearly independent (general solution of this form implies linear independence)

However, none of the answers tell why does linear independence imply generality of the solution obtained as a linear combination of the two functions. How do we know there is no other function that is a solution and that is outside the span of the two solutions $y_1, y_2$?

The [course](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FundamentalSetsofSolutions.aspx#mjx-eqn-eqeq1) I've been following for a while gives a proof that is unclear to me. It says that for a solution to be general, it must satisfy the general initial conditions $y(t_0) = y_0, y'(t_0) = y'_0$, so I guess this means, for all $t_0, y_0$ and $y'_0$. But how do we know that, even if our solution $y$ does in fact, satisfy any initial conditions, there is no other solution that satisfies some set of initial conditions for some $(t_0, y_0, y'_0)$, but does not fall in the form of $y$?

Comment: This is literally due to the *uniqueness* statement of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem. Identical initial conditions implies identical solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a general $n$-th order linear homogeneous ODE:
$$\sum_{i=0}^na_i(t)y^{(i)}(t)=0\tag{1}$$
where $a_n(t)\neq 0$ on a certain interval $J$ around a point $t_0$.

First, we should emphasize that solutions of the ODE $(1)$ are only defined on some small intervals. So what we want to prove is:

> If $t_0$ is a point on which all $a_i$ are defined and $C^1$ on some interval around $t_0$, and $a_n(t_0)\neq 0$, then there exists an interval $I$ around $t_0$ such that the solution set of $(1)$ has dimension $n$.
>
> Conversely, if $K$ is any interval on which $a_n\neq 0$, then there exist $n$ linearly independent solutions $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ of $(1)$, then these solutions generate the whole solution set of $(1)$ on $K$.

The easiest way is to use the [Picard-Lindelof Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), which works in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here is a restricted version of the general statement:

> **Theorem [Picard-Lindelof]**: Consider a Cauchy problem
> $$y'(t)=F(t,y(t)),\qquad y(t_0)=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)\tag{2}$$
> where $F=F(t,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a function, $C^1$ from some neighbourhood of $(t_0,f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
>
> - There exists an interval $I$ around $t_0$ and a fucntion $y=y(t)$ which is a solution of $(2)$. (This is the existence of solutions.)
> - Any two solutions $y_1,y_2$ of $(2)$, defined on intervals $I$ and $K$, coincide on $I\cap K$. (This is the "uniqueness" of solutions.)

---

Solving the ODE $(1)$ is equivalent to solving the following ODE on $n$ dimensions: Again, recall that we assume $a(t_0)\neq 0$ on some interval $J$ around $t_0$. Let $z(t)=(z_0(t),\ldots,z_{n-1}(t))$. Then consider the problem
$$z'(t)=F(t,z(t))\tag{3}$$
where $F(t,x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1})=\left(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_i(t)}{a_n(t)}x_i\right)$.

The equation $(3)$ means that
$$z_0'=z_1,\qquad z_1'=z_2,\ldots\qquad\text{or more generally }z_i=z_0^{(i)},$$
and $z_{n-1}'=-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_i(t)}{a_n(t)}z_i$.

Therefore, $z$ is a solution of $(3)$ iff $y:=z_0$ is a solution of $(1)$. Moreover, the map $z\mapsto z_0=y$ is a linear bijection from the solution space of $(3)$ to the solution space of $(1)$, so they have the same dimensions.

The function $F$ is defined and $C^1$ on $J\times\mathbb{R}^n$. Take a basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and solutions $z^1,\ldots,z^n$ of $(3)$, defined on some interval $I$ around $t_0$, and satisfying $z^i(t_0)=e_i$. These $z^i$ are clearly linearly independent.

If $z$ is any other solution of $(3)$ on $I$, write $z(t_0)=\sum\lambda_i e_i$. By the uniqueness part of Picard-Lindelof, $z=\sum\lambda_i z^i$ on $I$.

Comment: It's been over a year, but this is the first time I was actually able to understand your answer. I was missing sooo much background in linear algebra and metric spaces but now I think I was able to get the general idea of your proof. I have to write it on a paper and complete the details in order to fully understand. However, I have one question regarding the uniqueness of solutions in Picard-Lindeloff theorem. If there exists a unique solution on an interval $I=[t_0-k,t_0+k]$ and we find a solution on $H\supset K\supset I$ and another one on $K$, how do we know they are the same on $H\cap K$?

Comment: @StefanOctavian Under the hypotheses of Picard-Lindelof, if two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ of the ODE, defined on intervals $I$ and $J$ coincide on *any* point of $I\cap J$, then they coincide on *all* of $I$ and $J$. This is the magic: The set $P=\{x:y_1(x)=y_2(x)\}$ is nonempty, open in $I\cap J$ (by uniqueness of Picard-Lindelof) and closed. Since $I\cap J$ is an interval, hence connected, then $P=I\cap J$. The uniqueness part of Picard-Lindelof works "locally everywhere".

Comment: I don't really understand this part: "open in $I \cap J$ (by uniqueness of Picard-Lindelof)". If we take a point $x\in P$, how does the existence of an interval centered at $t_0$ that is included in $P$ guarantee the existence of an open interval centered at  $x$ that is included in $P$?

Comment: @StefanOctavian You don't use Picard-Lindelof around $t_0$; you use it around $x$. If $y_1(x)=y_2(x)$ and $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to the ODE, then by Picard-Lindelof they should be equal on a small neighbourhood around $x$. Forget about $t_0$. That is what I mean by "locally everywhere".

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. Let $P=\{x\in I\cap J\ |\ y_1(x) = y_2(x) \}$. Then, for all $x \in P$, both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to the same ODE but with initial conditions $y(x) = y_{1/2}(x)$. Then, by uniqueness of Picard-Lindelof, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x, \epsilon) \subset P$. This proves that $P$ is open in $I \cap J$. To prove that $P$ is closed, assume $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $P$, since $y$ are continuous, $\lim_{x\to x_0} y_1(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} y_2(x) = y_1(x_0) = y_2(x_0),\ x_0\in P$, so it contains all its accumulation points. Is this correct?

Comment: @StefanOctavian Yes, that is a complete and correct argument

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being annoying, but there is one more thing I don't understand. In the first blockquote, the second statement, I can only see how that would work if $a_n(t) \ne 0$ on all of $K$, or if $a_n(t) = 0$ only on its margins. Could you tell me how to prove that when $K$ has points (isolated or not) where $a_n(t) = 0$?

Comment: @StefanOctavian Yes, you are right. The argument only works if $a_n\neq 0$ on the interval (otherwise, the function $F$ defined below (3) doesn't even make sense). To give an example: The first order ODE $y(x)-2x^3y(x)=0$ has two smooth linearly independent solutions on $\mathbb{R}$: the "positive" Gaussian$$y_+(x)=\begin{cases}\exp(x^{-2})&\text{if }x>0\\0&\text{o/w}\end{cases}$$ and the "negative" Gaussian $$y_-(x)=y_+(-x).$$Good catch. Corrected.

Comment: You know, I still wonder what was actually your way of proving that second statement, because I'm not sure I'm seeing it the same way: basically, partitioning $K$, PL guarantees a unique solution with $z^i(t_0) = {\bf e_i}$ on the entire $K$ (right?). So, applying the same logic as in the end of your answer, that's it.